# Show Route Loading Animation in Angular After a Waiting Period

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have some routes that load from an external module (login, callback, unauthorized, etc) and sometimes it takes 2 or 3 seconds for the app to navigate to the route. While it's waiting to route to the navigation page, the screen is blank, except for the navbar at the top. I would like to add a loading message while it's routing. I found a way by subscribing to the `router.events` Observable:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe(event => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.routeLoading = true;
        } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
            this.routeLoading = false;
        }
    });
}
```

But would like to actually only do this if the Navigation takes more than half a second, for example. Many routes, once we're logged in, are mostly instantaneous, and in those cases I don't want to have the loader flash on the screen.

Is there a way to do this? I'm thinking something like using the `pipe` operator, and the `debounceTime` operator might work, but I'm not entirely sure. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: the idea is nice, but if you don't know the time when the navigation end before, how you can choose to set routeLoading? maybe a slow fade in animation on the loader/spinner so if it is quick to load i will barely visible before it get removed (fade out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do somthing like this :

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd),
  debounceTime(500)
).subscribe(event => this.routeLoading = event instanceof NavigationStart)
```

Explanation:

1. Only use `NavigationStart` and `NavigationEnd` (you can add `NavigationCancel` too)
2. Debounce events (if one is emitted before debounce end, it will not taken in consideration)
3. Set value dynamically (last call will always be NavigationEnd or NavigationCancel) so it will end with `false` value

Answer (score 0):

I used @Gilsdav's answer to start and it works perfectly. I made a minor change so that the debounce time only occurs on `NavigationStart`. This way the loader goes away immediately on `NavigationEnd` but starts after the 500 millisecond wait time on `NavigationStart`. Here's how to do it that way:

```
this._router.events
    .pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        debounce(event => (event instanceof NavigationStart ? timer(500) : EMPTY)),
    )
    .subscribe(event => {
        this.routeLoading = event instanceof NavigationStart;
    });
```

The `debounce` operator is similar to `debounceTime`, but using it gave me the option to do a conditional time for the debounce based on the `instanceof` the `event` result.